# JQuery Dialog being loaded with entire page as content?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, ajax, dialog

I want to have a very basic JQuery dialog, but I can't make it work.

I used examples from the website, as I have before (and it works), but for this particular project the dialog is acting weird. This is problably a silly mistake I'm making, but I coulnd't find it, so I hope you guys can give me a hand.

When I call:

```
$('#TextOnlyDialog').dialog();
```

I get the dialog, but I also get the entire original html page inside it (when it should be behind it) and everything behind it is gone.

Here's what I'm doing (not the whole code, but the basic structure):

```
<link type="text/css" href="Extras/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Extras/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Extras/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Initialize() {
        $('#TextOnlyDialog').dialog();
    }
</script>
<body onload="Initialize();">
 <form id="MainForm" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="PageScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="PageUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="TextOnlyDialog" title="Dialog Title">
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't have a closing `</div>` on your dialog

Should be:

```
<div id="TextOnlyDialog" title="Dialog Title"></div>
```

Secondly, have you tried taking it out of the `<asp:UpdatePanel` and just putting it at the bottom of your html, before the `</form>`. It's a dialog and doesn't need to be tied into anything else.

Finally. You normally initialise the dialog using `$('#TextOnlyDialog').dialog();`  but to open it it's normally `$('#TextOnlyDialog').dialog('open');` and `$('#TextOnlyDialog').dialog('close');` to close it.

I may be wrong on that last point, though that's how I use it myself.